# Check if key is in a dictionary

Tags: python

I've created a dictionary and I'm looking for a key in it. When I run the program, it doesn't return anything and says its taking too long to execute. I've looked at other similar questions but they don't seem to work for me. Please help!!

```
y={'5':'8'}
x=input('hi?')
if x in y:
    print 'yeah'
else:
    print 'nope'
```

Comment: Are you using Python3 or Python2.7 ?

Comment: `"says its taking too long to execute"` - *What* is saying that? How are you running this code?

Comment: I'm using repl.it. It's python 2.7.2

Comment: So you should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `raw_input()` as `input()` in python 2.7 *evaluates the input data*:

```
y={'5':'8'}
x=raw_input('hi?')

if x in y:
    print 'yeah'
else:
    print 'nope'
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but what do you mean return an int?

Comment: As @MatthewTrevor edited, `input()` evaluates what you enter, so if you enter a number, `x` will be type int so it  won't be found as a key in the dictionary.